# Assembly Language Division-Remainder DX register

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, division

I have the program almost done. I am trying to divide CBA0123h by B000h. The quotient comes out right. However, the remainder which is supposed to be in the dx register should be: EA61 (http://www.miniwebtool.com/hex-calculator/?number1=CBA0123&operate=4&number2=B000), but instead its A123. I think this has something to do with little endian or something. But I need to fix this. How can I? Do I rotate bits? I never seen how to do this before. How can I get the correct remainder from this division problem?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
unsigned short int IDQUO = 0x0;
unsigned short int IDREM = 0x0;

    mov     dx, 0CBAh       
    mov     ax, 0123h       
    mov     bx, 0B000h      
    div     bx              
    mov     IDQUO, ax       
    mov     IDREM, dx       
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think the remainder should be `0xea61`? `0xa123` is [the correct answer](http://ideone.com/KnE4c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%x\n", 0xCBA0123 % 0xB000);
}
```

Output: `a123`

Comment: http://www.miniwebtool.com/hex-calculator/?number1=CBA0123&operate=4&number2=B000

Comment: @user1193717: The remainder is not the same thing as the fractional part of the division result.

Answer (score 6):

CBA0123h = B000h * 1282 + A123h. The DX value is correct.

Comment: http://www.miniwebtool.com/hex-calculator/?number1=CBA0123&operate=4&number2=B000

Comment: @user1193717 That's not how a remainder works. That's the binary representation of `CBA0123h / B000h`.

Comment: @user1193717: That's not giving you a remainder. Quoting: `CBA0123h ÷ B000 = 1282.ea61745d17` - that's a fractional result.